# SELECT statement returns nothing in SQLite

Tags: sqlite

I have a table in which there's a column of type BLOB. Another column is of type 'text'. Something like:

```
CREATE TABLE Tbl(TXT text, BLB blob);
```

Now I've inserted a few records using:

```
INSERT INTO Tbl(TXT) VALUES("whatever");
```

As you can see nothing was defined for BLB. But each time that I issue a query like:

```
SELECT * FROM 'Tbl' WHERE 'TXT'="whatever";
```

I get nothing at all without any error message or anything. My primary guess was that the problem might have something to do with BLB being null or undefined or something like that. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query should be:

```
SELECT * FROM Tbl WHERE TXT="whatever";
```

You are specifying strings for the table name and for the column. SQL lets you perform queries on values, not just tables.